# kpagecount of a present page is zero

Tags: linux, memory-management, paging, virtual-memory

How is it possible, for a page whose `present bit` is set, to have a `kpagecount` equal to `zero`?

According to linux documentation:

> - /proc/kpagecount.  This file contains a 64-bit count of the number
>     of    times each page is mapped, indexed by PFN.

I did a toy application, and I printed out all pagemap entries for all `vma's` of a program.
I know, that `kpagecount` could be above `1`, when a page is shared among different processes. Typical examples of these are the `c-o-w` of `fork` calls, or any `libraries` that are used by multiple programs.

In the case that it is zero, is when the last program that was using that particular page, does not need it any more, so the kernel can reclaim that page.
Is that correct?

However in the case of my toy app, I haven't issued any free command yet. So it does not make sense to have a `heap` page in ram (`present bit` set), and having the `kpagecount` to `0`. So, is this counter accurate? Or am I missing something else?

Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps it has just been unmapped from the last process that was using it, so that the kernel *can* reclaim it, but there has not been enough memory activity since that that the kernel *has needed to* reclaim it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a week after, I 've found the answer on the`Understanding the Linux Kernel`book.

The `_count` variable, of the `Page Descriptor` structure, holds a reference counter to the page.

- if it is set to -1, then the page frame is free, and it can be reclaimed by the kernel
- if it is >=0 then it is assigned to 1 or more processes, or by the kernel itself
- the `page_count()` function returns the value of `_count`, **increased by one**, which is the number of processes that share the page

Also, then `_count` is increased when:

- the page is inserted into the `swap cache`
- the flag `PG_private` in `page descriptor` is set